# Merging data from 2 excel files into one master file

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 excel workbooks with 2 tabs each and I want to copy the data from only 1 tab (from each workbook) into a different "master log" workbook. These 2 excel are named "Station 1 Daily Log" and "Station 2 Daily Log". These 2 files are in one folder of my computer.

The code I currently use copies the data from each of the workbook's tab into the same "Master Log" tab, but "Station 2  daily log" is replacing "station 1 daily log" data. My "Master Log" workbook consists of 2 tabs:

1. one where the file path, file name and tab is defined for the stations name "FilesSheet"
2. one where I want the data to go into "MasterSheet"

I used the lastrow but it did not work, because I don't know where to place it.

```
Sub UpdateMasterLog()
 Dim MainWorkbook As Workbook, Station1Workbook As Workbook, Station2Workbook As Workbook
 Dim FilesSheet As Worksheet, MasterSheet As Worksheet
 Dim InputFilePath As String, InputFileName As String, InputFileTab As String
 Dim rngToCopy As Range

Set MainWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set FilesSheet = Sheets("Files")
Set MasterSheet = Sheets("Master Log")

With FilesSheet
     InputFilePath = .Cells(1, 2)
     InputFileName = .Cells(2, 2)
     InputFileTab = .Cells(3, 2)
      .Cells(4, 2) = FileDateTime(InputFilePath + InputFileName)
 End With

 Set Station1Workbook = Workbooks.Open(InputFilePath + InputFileName)
 MasterSheet.Cells.ClearContents
 Station1Workbook.Sheets(InputFileTab).Cells.Copy Destination:=MasterSheet.Cells
 Station1Workbook.Close Savechanges:=False

 With FilesSheet
    InputFilePath = .Cells(5, 2)
    InputFileName = .Cells(6, 2)
    InputFileTab = .Cells(7, 2)
    .Cells(8, 2) = FileDateTime(InputFilePath + InputFileName)
 End With

 Set Station2Workbook = Workbooks.Open(InputFilePath + InputFileName)
 Station2Workbook.Sheets(InputFileTab).Cells.Copy Destination:=MasterSheet.Cells
 Station2Workbook.Close Savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

I tried last row and other codes I found online but it was giving me range errors, etc. or It just shows Station 2 data only.

Comment: You are using `Destination:=MasterSheet.Cells` for both copy, hence the reason is getting overwritten. You also copy everything... Surely these sheets are not completely full, or wouldn't fit in 1. You should define the ranges you want to copy/paste in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I do want both of them to go the same destination, but Station 2 data to go to the next empty row after Station 1 data. For the ranges, what can I use to specify only column ranges? because rows will vary daily.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go... i`ve just reused your code as much as possible, but in an ideal world you can reduce this to at least a half. I recommend having some headers in your master sheet, and only clear under the headers, and copy accordingly...

```
Sub UpdateMasterLog()
    Dim MainWorkbook As Workbook: Set MainWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Dim Station1Workbook As Workbook, Station2Workbook As Workbook

    Dim FilesSheet As Worksheet: Set FilesSheet = MainWorkbook.Sheets("Files")
    Dim MasterSheet As Worksheet: Set MasterSheet = MainWorkbook.Sheets("Master Log")
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet

    MasterSheet.Cells.ClearContents

    Dim InputFilePath As String, InputFileName As String, InputFileTab As String
    Dim rngToCopy As Range

    Dim lRowDst As Long, lRowSrc As Long, lColSrc As Long

    'Station1Workbook
    With FilesSheet
        InputFilePath = .Cells(1, 2)
        InputFileName = .Cells(2, 2)
        InputFileTab = .Cells(3, 2)
        .Cells(4, 2) = FileDateTime(InputFilePath + InputFileName)
    End With

    Set Station1Workbook = Workbooks.Open(InputFilePath + InputFileName)
    Set wsSrc = Station1Workbook.Sheets(InputFileTab)

    With MasterSheet
        lRowDst = 1 'if all clear should, last row is 1... ideally should have some headers and clear only under headers...

        With wsSrc
            lRowSrc = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lColSrc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        End With

        'Allocate the values
        .Range(.Cells(lRowDst, 1), .Cells(lRowSrc, lColSrc)).Value = wsSrc.Range(wsSrc.Cells(1, 1), wsSrc.Cells(lRowSrc, lColSrc)).Value
    End With

    Station1Workbook.Close Savechanges:=False

    'Station2Workbook
    With FilesSheet
       InputFilePath = .Cells(5, 2)
       InputFileName = .Cells(6, 2)
       InputFileTab = .Cells(7, 2)
       .Cells(8, 2) = FileDateTime(InputFilePath + InputFileName)
    End With

    Set Station2Workbook = Workbooks.Open(InputFilePath + InputFileName)
    Set wsSrc = Station2Workbook.Sheets(InputFileTab)

    With MasterSheet
        lRowDst = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        With wsSrc
            lRowSrc = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lColSrc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        End With

        'Allocate the values
        .Range(.Cells(lRowDst + 1, 1), .Cells(lRowDst + lRowSrc, lColSrc)).Value = wsSrc.Range(wsSrc.Cells(2, 1), wsSrc.Cells(lRowSrc, lColSrc)).Value
    End With

    Station2Workbook.Close Savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** fixed second copy ranges.

Comment: Thank you! very close, however it is only copying all data from Station1 including header (which is good!) and only copied 1 row from station2 data in this case, the header. How can I copy all the data from station2 under station1 data NOT including the header of station2?

Comment: Fixed, please see the updated code... was copying everything, but just to 1 row as i forgot a variable.